# How to use full length of the upper part of the content and below of it is a content with a sidebar?

Tags: sidebar, content

Can anyone help me with my problem although its simple but I'm just newbie in wordpress?

Right now I'm using the default template of the theme with sidebar. So what I want to happen is above the content of the page below the menu is to put a content across the page, but only in homepage I don't want to see it to all of the page.

Sorry for my English I'm having a hard time explaining it in English, Hope you understand what I'm trying to point out.

Here is the current site http://ftcanada.com/
Here is what I want to insert http://awesomescreenshot.com/02a1ycnn26

Please help me...

Here is the content.php

When I insert a code above the article id the content appear in every page. What I want to happen is to display it just in homepage.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>
            <hgroup>
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'catchbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <h3 class="entry-format"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'catchbox' ); ?></h3>
            </hgroup>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'catchbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php catchbox_posted_on(); ?>
                <?php if ( comments_open() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                    <span class="sep sep-comment"> &mdash; </span>
                    <span class="comments-link">
                        <?php comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &darr;', 'catchbox'), __('1 Comment &darr;', 'catchbox'), __('% Comments &darr;', 'catchbox')); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

     <?php 
        $options = catchbox_get_theme_options();
        $current_content_layout = $options['content_layout'];
        $catchbox_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

    if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php elseif ( $current_content_layout=='excerpt' && !empty( $catchbox_excerpt ) ) : // Only display Featured Image and Excerpts if checked in Theme Option ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'catchbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-slider'); ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'catchbox' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 
            'before'        => '<div class="page-link"><span class="pages">' . __( 'Pages:', 'catchbox' ) . '</span>',
            'after'         => '</div>',
            'link_before'   => '<span>',
            'link_after'    => '</span>',
        ) ); 
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php $show_sep = false; ?>
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'catchbox' ) );
            if ( $categories_list ):
        ?>
        <span class="cat-links">
            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'catchbox' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', $categories_list );
            $show_sep = true; ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'catchbox' ) );
            if ( $tags_list ):
            if ( $show_sep ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <?php endif; // End if $show_sep ?>
        <span class="tag-links">
            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Tagged</span> %2$s', 'catchbox' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list );
            $show_sep = true; ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif; // End if $tags_list ?>
        <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>

        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <?php if ( $show_sep ) : ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <?php endif; // End if $show_sep ?>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'catchbox' ) . '</span>', __( '<b>1</b> Reply', 'catchbox' ), __( '<b>%</b> Replies', 'catchbox' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; // End if comments_open() ?>

        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'catchbox' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- #entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi winresh24, this is not a help forum, what have you tried to do so far? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wrap the additional content in a conditional so that it only shows up where you need it to. You probably want either [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) (for the *Blog Posts Index*) or [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) (for the *Site Front Page*), like this:

```
<?php
if (is_home()) {
  // your addition content
} ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Ohh thanks for the response I give it a try..Hope it will work thanks dude